# Get Full Qualified Domain Name from user AD entry

Tags: c#, active-directory

Given an AD entry, how can I get the full qualified domain name of the user?

Up to now I used

```
((string)directoryEntry.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value).Split('@')[1]
```

but `userPrincipalName` is not a required property, so I guess I need a fallback...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that "cn" is a mandatory attribute in AD,and in my experience it has the same value as the login value, so you can try that.
Im not 100% sure though, so try it and let met know, if not i will delete this answer.

Hopefully it helps.

Comment: With my example user, `userPrincipalName` is `matslehmann@intra.contoso.com`, `cn` is `Mats Lehmann`, and I need the domain, which is `intra.contoso.com`. But thx for the try.

Comment: Maybe the sAMAccountName? also mandatory. Take a look at this site for more attributes : http://www.kouti.com/tables/userattributes.htm